# Split a MySQL single row into multiple rows based on a field's number value divided by

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to split a single row into multiple rows based upon one of the row's fields that has a number value (QTY in the example below). I need that row split based on being divided by 600. So if row has 1800 the original row will be duplicated/split into 3 rows each totaling 600. I also want the sequence recorded for each split row as well as the result of how many records were created as TTL_RCRDS example below (this I can probably figure out myself). Also, I need the last split record to record the remaining amount just in case the number cannot be split evenly by 600. See Order 67890 in below New_Table example.

This is the first time I have done calculations within a query of this kind. So I am completely lost on how to approach it and I have exhausted my ability to research it and find any directions on learning how to do this kind of calculations within MySQL or possibly in PHP if not possible in SQL.

The below example should give you an idea of what I was trying to explain above.

Source_Table:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| ORDER | CLIENT | ITEM | ITEM_DESC       | QTY  | STATUS   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 23456 | ABC    | LW1  | LW1 Description | 1800 | Bindery  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 78901 | DEF    | LW2  | LW2 Description | 1200 | Bindery  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 67890 | GHI    | LWC  | LWC Description | 900  | Bindery  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Expected Output in New_Table:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ORDER | CLIENT | ITEM | ITEM_DESC       | QTY  | STATUS   | SEQ | TTL_RCRDS |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 23456 | ABC    | LW1  | LW1 Description | 600  | Bindery  | 1   | 3         |
| 23456 | ABC    | LW1  | LW1 Description | 600  | Bindery  | 2   | 3         |
| 23456 | ABC    | LW1  | LW1 Description | 600  | Bindery  | 3   | 3         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 78901 | DEF    | LW2  | LW2 Description | 600  | Bindery  | 1   | 2         |
| 78901 | DEF    | LW2  | LW2 Description | 600  | Bindery  | 2   | 2         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 67890 | GHI    | LWC  | LWC Description | 600  | Bindery  | 1   | 2         |
| 67890 | GHI    | LWC  | LWC Description | 300  | Bindery  | 2   | 2         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I think you are going to have to do that in another place for example a PHP script or other language

Comment: I guess I went the SQL route because I knew I could schedule a stored procedure. If I do this in PHP (which could possibly be much easier for me) I will either have to run the script manually through a web browser or find a way to automate a php script file as a scheduled task. Manual would be fine and could be part of the process if there is no way to automate a php file.

Comment: A CRON Job if you are Linux or Task Scheduler if you are Windows